# Dynamically Changing the Type of a TextField After Being Setup via Xib

Tags: ios, objective-c, xib, objective-c-runtime

I have a `UITableViewCell` subclass (`CustomTableViewCell`) which has a custom text field `CustomTextField` specified from within the xib file.

I now would like to use `CustomTableViewCell` from a table view that requires a date text field. However, `CustomTextField` is intended to be used as an alpha-numeric text field. I would like to re-instantiate it as a `CustomDateTextField` during runtime (after instructing the `CustomTableViewCell` what type of text field instance to use).

I would like to merely instantiate a different instance type while leaving all other settings and auto layout constraints in place. Is this possible? How would I go about doing this?

Comment: I think what you can do is, use same textfield and set 'keyboardType' property of it dynamically which can resolve your issue instead of having 2 different types for textfield.

Comment: I second nikBhosale's comment.

Comment: Yeah, I was considering doing that but I have a custom text field that I already use all over the app for dates. If I go with checking the ‘keyboardType’ property it would require a lot of additional setup that I don’t want to replicate considering I already have it implemented in ‘CustomDateTextField’. I imagine what I am asking should be possible with the help of the ObjC runtime, I am asking here to see if anyone has already done this before I research how to go about it myself.